# Is it safe to interrupt own thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a class which is creating a thread and stores it. While doing some stuff this thread can notice some error, notify the class and interrupt it self.

```
class foo {
public:
    enum mode {
        run=0,
        booboo,
        stop
    };

    foo() {
        th_ = boost::thread(boost::bind(&foo::bar, this));
        mode_ = run;
    }

    ~foo() {
        stop();
    }

    void stop() {
        mode_ = stop;
        th_.join();
    }

    void bar {
        for(;;) {
            if(mode_ == stop)
            return;

            if(error) {
                mode_ = booboo;
                th_.interrupt();

                // the sleep is the interruption point
                boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::nanoseconds(0));
            }

            // do some stuff
        }
    }

private:
    boost::thread th_;
    mode          mode_;
};
```

According to [boost::thread.interrupt](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption) there is no indication that this won't work. If I understand it right, `interrupt` will mark the thread to interrupt it on the next interruption_point which is in my case the call of sleep_for.

On my machine and OS, it is working, so my question is, is it safe to do so?

Comment: If the documentation does not say explicitly it might not work, then I see no reason to think the contrary. Is there any specific issue that makes you think it might?

Comment: @Purrfection actually i just want to be sure.

Comment: I also see no reason why it should not work, but I see no real use for it. If you interrupt a thread it will throw a `boost::thread_interrupted` exception at the first interruption point it encounters, unless interruption is disabled. I.e. You could just throw the exception explicitely instead.